# How can an event subscriber have access to the entity type?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm using entity_print for PDF generation on two node types. I'd like each to have its own orientation configuration (or just have one override the default). There is an event in entity_print where configuration can be set at run-time, so I have a simple event subscriber, with a method to override the orientation, but I can't seem to get the last piece, which is the entity (bundle label) to switch on.

How can an event subscriber have access to the entity type?

Comment: You have an entity object in code? You should have a `bundle()` method to return the type. Node also has the convienient method `getType()` for node objects to get their node type.

Comment: @Kevin That's the problem, the event object is only storing the type of the print object, not the object being printed. I think upon further investigation, I may actually need to subscribe to a pre-send event to get this.

Answer (score 0):

The event should have the entities its acting on. Have you tried the following?

```
$entities = $event->getEntities();
```

To get the bundle:

```
$bundle = $event->getEntities()[0]->bundle();
```